# Meteor file system

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a question about meteor file structure. I´m coming from JAVA so maybe I'm thinking way too complicated.

When you create a new Meteor project (using osx shell), it creates you a folder like `/usr/MyUsername/projectname/`.

Inside you'll find the: `project.js`, `project.html`, `project.css` and the `.meteor` folder.

What I want to do now is:

Create a structure like: `/usr/MyUsername/projectname/`

There I want to create a server an a client folder. where I put the `client.js` and the `server.js` into.

**Where do I set the references?** For example with the following code in the `project/client/client.js`:

```
Meteor.call('somefunc', someobj);
```

I have in the `project/server/server.js` the following code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({
      'somefunc':function(someobj){
        CalEvent.insert(someobj);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Where in the client.js do I tell where the server.js is? and how?

Comment: Please make sure to re-read yourself, using the dictionary of your browser if needed. Also, no need to say thanks on this website, we're all here to help you.

Comment: ok. im always used to say thanks, when peaople solving problems for or with me. will try following the rules beter :)

Answer (score 1):

Long story short : you don't have to worry about references, as long as you put things that belong in the client under `client/` and server-side stuff under `server/` you're good to go.

No need to wrap your code with `Meteor.isServer` blocks if it lives under `server/`.
You don't need the `Meteor.startup` block either, the code you put in these sections is rerun everytime the server is restarted but you only need your method to be defined once.

The `meteor` tool build process takes care of merging all the client files and sends them to the browser for execution, likewise it's merging server files and spawn a Node.js process to execute the resulting bundle.